# TensorFlow placeholder for InputList

Tags: tensorflow

Some raw operations use InputLists, not (only) simple Inputs. I want to add a Placeholder to my Graph, and during TF_SessionRun add the actual array of tensors. I have two problems with it:

TF_SessionRun does not talk about InputList, it only knows Inputs. I assume (correct me if I am wrong), that from a TF_Session point of view, an InputList is just an Input (giving the first element of the array).

I cannot solve to have a Placeholder in the Graph. Defining Placeholder requires to give its data type, but in an InputList every Tensor can have its own data type.
I am looking either for a data type "DT_List" or similar indicating that the given Placeholder is a list of different tensors, OR looking for another raw operations, called "ListPlaceholder" or similar, to cater for this purpose.
How shall it be done?

P.S. Imagine raw operation Save. It's third parameter is an InputList of Tensors to save. I made a Graph that works well for a single Tensor, but I cannot solve it for multiple ones in one go.

Answer (score 0):

It seems after a lot of checking, that I incorrectly guessed that there is (or should be) such a thing as an InputList input. The inputs to Session.Run are always single Tensors and as such no "Placeholder for list" exists. In the mentioned "Save" elementary operation, the "data" parameter - as guessed - has to be added using TF_AddInputList, but the list of TF_Outputs in its parameter list has to be assembled from individual TF_Output elements and cannot be retrieved as one TF_OutputList from a "Placeholder" like node.

If my conclusion is wrong, please correct me.